Error Importing Module in Azure Powershell Runbook
I have a Powershell 7.2 script in an Automation Runbook that drops 18 databases in our lower environment and then restores them from our production environment. The script uses a managed identity. If I have it open in Visual Studio Code, and connect to Azure Runbooks from there, I am able to run it locally without any errors. However, when I publish it to Azure, and run it as "Start Automation Test Job", it fails with the following error:

I have verified the module is installed under the automation account.

I am using this command to import the module.
Import-Module -Name Az.Sql -RequiredVersion 5.2.0 -Force
I would appreciate some direction here. I've tried removing the module from the automation account and re-adding it and have the same issue.

Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#prerequisites

That looks like it's for devops. I'm just using a runbook in Azure in the test environment there.

Have you added import-module command in the PowerShell script? @camromere

It is for both devops and non devops.

@Jahnavi Yes, in my original message I put the exact text that I am using.
Import-Module -Name Az.Sql -RequiredVersion 5.2.0 -Force
I've tried with and without -RequiredVersion and with and without -Force and I still get the error.

@camromere I am also facing similar issues with my runbook, but not with Az.SQL. For me, Issue is with Az.Automation module. My scheduled job fails once in a while as the module is not getting imported.
What I am planning is to create a new runtime environment and get the module imported. Will let you know if that helped.
Cheers !

This issue is transient and comes when there is a version compatibility conflict.
Firstly, make sure that the version of the Az.Sql module you're using 5.2.0 is compatible with the Automation Account's runbook runtime version.
And also check the version in your local environment and the Azure automation account if there is any version compatibility conflict.
Refer PowerShell Gallery modules for the above information.
Once you have installed, add the import command in the PowerShell script as given below.
Import-Module Az.sql -Force
In Azure Automation account, module loading takes an ample amount of time so wait until the complete module importing is done.
Also check the Get-Module -Listavailable to check if it is loaded properly.
I have executed a sample script for dropping databases according to your requirement as shown below and it worked in local vs code without any issues.

Once I deployed it to an automation account, I was able to view the successful results as shown.

If still the issue persists, you can use the Hybrid Worker in an automation account instead of running directly in Azure.
